# How to use aggregation in MongoDB Atlas to search keyword/string present in object inside another object?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I want to search documents in my database if the enterd string/keyword present in any of the field in the document.By using atlas serach,i am able to find the document if the string present in any fields.but i have an object present in the document.I need to search through that object also.
inshort i need to serach the string in the object inside another object.

**collections:**
products(it has 'companyId' as foreign key),
companies

**$lookup**
`

```
{
  from: 'companies',
  localField:'companyId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'company'
}
```

`

**$unwind**

`

```
{
path:'$company'
}
```

`

**now looks like this:**

`

```
{
  name:"abcd",
  price:"21",
  text:"aaa",
  comapny:{
          name:"bbbb"
          }
 }
`
```

Now i have 'products' with with its field with 'company' as key having value as object.
Now i want to search the keyword in all fields in 'products' including the 'company' which is an object.

Comment: Is this what you need https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/lookup-with-search/ ?

Comment: I found that atlas search only works on MongoDB version 6.0 or greater, as a free account cloud providing version 5.0, is there any alternative to achieve the result